# JS: creating user input amount of rows

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to create user input amount of rows. I know how to do this with document.write but I can't get this to work with innerHTML.

This is what I've got so far:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  if ( (x >> 0) > 0 ) {
    for ( --- I've tried everything I can think of here but nothing works -- ) {
    document.getElementById("secondblock").innerHTML = x + "<br />"
    }
```

This bit:

```
if ( (x >> 0) > 0 ) {
```

is for making sure the input is a number -- I'm using the same input field for other (string) functions too. I'm sure there's some better way to check whether my var x is a number or not, but I've just been using this method.

This is what I'm trying to create (if user inputs number 5): 
1. 
2. 
3. 
4. 
5.

Comment: what is inside you for loop

Comment: Could you show the HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was that you were over-writing the innerHtml instead of appending.

here's an example of how you can change innerHTML whenever the input changes:

```
<input value="5" id="myText" onchange="myFunction()">
<div id="secondblock"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("secondblock").innerHTML = "";
  if ( (x >> 0) > 0 ) {
    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        document.getElementById("secondblock").innerHTML += (i + 1) + "<br />"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the replies, this one works and is simple enough for my beginner butt to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("secondblock").innerHTML += x + "<br />"
```

Full example

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
for(let i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    x.innerHTML += i + "<br />"
}
```

}

With innerHTML you are resetting the innerHTML every time. So to get the desired output you just need to concat the previous innerHTML as well. Try the code below and you will see the innerHTML resetting to the last insert.

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
for(let i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    x.innerHTML += i + "<br />"
}
x.innerHTML = 'Tadaaaa'
```

}

Comment: Might be even more helpful if you explain why this works and why the original one doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are replacing inputs in for loop everytime. Instead you need to concat every input and then replace with innerHTML. Check below:

```
function myFunction() {
  let value = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  let x = parseInt(value)
  if (!isNaN(x) && parseInt(x) > 0 ) {
    let finalStr = '';
    for(let i=1;i<=x;i++){
       finalStr += i +'<br />'
    }
    document.getElementById("secondblock").innerHTML = finalStr;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the function get called?

put console.log in first line to check

if it doesn't get called check your html do you have an event attached with the function?

for the function:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log('do i get called?');
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    if ( (x >> 0) > 0 ) {
        //get the element
        var el = document.getElementById("secondblock");
        //clean html for next call
        el.innerHTML = '';
        for (let i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            // you were overriding second block instead of adding to it
            el.innerHTML += i + "<br />"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below:

```
function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
      if ( isNaN(x) ) {
        for ( --- I've tried everything I can think of here but nothing works -- ) 
        {
            document.getElementById("secondblock").innerHTML = x + "<br />"
        }
       }
  }
```

OR

```
function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
      if ( typeof(x) == 'number' ) {
        for ( --- I've tried everything I can think of here but nothing works -- ) 
        {
            document.getElementById("secondblock").innerHTML = x + "<br />"
        }
      }
 }
```